# IIS 7.5 Slow serving page while it upload to another file host in a separate thread

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I am using Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5, the webpage loads very slowly around 5-10 second to open.

User can upload file on my website, after it finished uploading (file around 300MB), my server will create a new thread and using that thread to upload the file to another server. During this process client faces slowness on the whole website, which means that the whole server is busy because of the uploading process running in w3wp.

I can't write a program for uploading the file but instead relying on the w3wp. Anyone know how to optimize the process so that i can upload and also serves the site quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused....network and I/O bandwidth are limited finite resources, if you have two or more processes competing for the same resource, then use will deplete what is available to use for others.  If you want better performance, perhaps delaying the second transfer or queuing it until things die down a bit might help.